# Worry about life, body, health: obstacle for Arahataphala?

Tags: right-view, right-livelihood, life, past-lives

Is worry about life, body health, e.g. householding, status-maintaining, obstacles for Arahataphala? Is this in accordance with what the Teacher taught? And why is such an obstacle?

Would one believing no former, no next life (deny rebirth), not hold either strong on kaya (Sakkaya), worry about life and health, or falls into ideas of "abounding life will be Nibbana, end of suffering"?

Comment: Sadhu for effort in spell and gramma correction. Nevertheless "does" is more proper then "is". That does importand!

Answer (score 0):

Worry is an obstacle (to Enlightenment) and should be attended to with mindfulness.

Comment: Please read [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information about answering questions.

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism Stack Exchange. The system flagged this as a low quality answer. This answer is too short and doesn't contain enough details. Also, if possible, it is preferred to cite sources to support the answer. Did you intend it to be a [comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) under the question? If not, please see [this guide](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

Is worry about or attachment to life, health, material wealth, family, house-holding, career-building etc.  obstacles for Arahataphala?

Yes, of course. These are part of the ten fetters.

A person who has attained stream entry has only overcome the lowest three fetters, and would still be subject to the rest of the fetters.

> "There are these ten fetters. Which ten? Five lower fetters & five
> higher fetters. And which are the five lower fetters? Self-identity
> views, uncertainty, grasping at precepts & practices, sensual desire,
> & ill will. These are the five lower fetters. And which are the five
> higher fetters? Passion for form, passion for what is formless,
> conceit, restlessness, & ignorance. These are the five higher fetters.
> And these are the ten fetters."
> [AN 10.13](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.013.than.html)

Comment: And where does worry about stand, life, health fits in? Lower or higher fetter, which, good householder?

Comment: @Samana All of those are covered in sensual desire, passion for form, conceit etc.